# iOS - Set location of Keyboard with CustomGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uigesturerecognizer

Apps like 'iMessage' and 'Facebook Messenger' allow users to move the keyboard off the screen by swiping downward. I was able to set other views to move around the screen with a CustomGestureRecognizer. (snippet below)

```
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        let window = view?.window
        if state == .Failed {
            return
        } else if let loc = touches.first?.locationInView(window) {
            displacement = loc.y - swipeStartingY
            delegatePass?.didSlowSwipe(displacement)
            state = .Changed
        }
        super.touchesMoved(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
```

> How do these apps set the frame.origin.y of the keyboard to move it
>   down and off the screen?

--Solved

> How do I get my UITextView that sits above the keyboard to follow the keyboard, now that `scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .Interactive`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a callback from the gesture recognizer, loop through all the views to find which one is the responder (aka the current one being edited) and call the method "view.endEditing(true)" to cause the keyboard to dismiss.

The Facebook Messenger application just ends editing of the the text field causing the keyboard to dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the frame of the keyboard. To achieve that effect you call

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .Interactive
```